# Функция в onsubmit возвращает false, но форма всё равно отправляется на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование

Очень маленькая и простая HTML-форма с функций checkEmailInput() для проверки на заполненность input и валидации введенного e-mail адреса.

При разкоменченных алертах всё работает нормально до поры до времени: например, ввожу невалидный e-mail адрес, а функция всё правильно проверяет и выводит соответствующее предупреждение: "ВНИМАНИЕ! Введеный email адрес и т.д.", т.е. раз идет именно это фраза, значит, в итоге функция вернёт ложь.

НО сразу после срабатывает предупреждение, записанное в php-скрипте (где нет проверок кроме на пустоту), что почта успешно добавлена в БД, то есть в onsubmit возвращается из функции false, но данные всё равно текут на сервак.

```js
function checkEmailInput(inputID) {
  var email_value = document.getElementById(inputID).value;
  if (email_value != '') {
    var pattern = /^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\._-]*[a-z0-9]*@([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i;
    if (email_value.search(pattern) != 0) {
      //alert('ВНИМАНИЕ! Введеный email адрес не соответствует общим стандартам.');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    //alert('Поле для ввода e-mail адреса не должно оставаться пустым!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="email_sign" onsubmit="checkEmailInput('email_sign_form');" action="" method="POST">
  <input id="email_sign_form" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail адрес">
  <input id="submit_sign_form" type="submit" name="sign_btn" value="Подписаться">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считайте, что значение атрибута `onsubmit` обернуто в функцию. Код этой функции должен возвращать значение:

```
onsubmit="return checkEmailInput('email_sign_form');"
```

Comment: Честно, в первый раз такое вижу, но работает, хотя и как-то странно... Но спасибо!